# Java Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I have an `Item` class and 2 classes which extends this class named `CountableItem` and `UncountableItem`.

`CountableItem` has one instance variable named `quantity` and `UncountableItem` class has one instance variable named `weight`.

Theirs constructors are like

```
public CountableItem(int id, String name, double unitPrice, Date experitionDate,int quantity) {
super(id, name, unitPrice, experitionDate);
setQuantity(quantity);
}
```

and

```
public UncountableItem(int id, String name, double unitPrice, Date experitionDate,double weight) {
super(id, name, unitPrice, experitionDate);
setWeight(weight);
}
```

And in another class I hold items in an `ArrayList`

```
private ArrayList<Item> storeList = new ArrayList<>();
```

In main class users enters how many or how much he wants to buy.
But I cannot change the quantity or the weight because my arraylist hold items.
Please help :(

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't understand your question/what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking, but you should be able to check `if (item instanceof UncountableItem)`.

Comment: Before inserting elements in the arraylist, you have to create them. You can insert CountableItem and UncountableItem in that storeList. Set its attributes just after you create an instance and before insertion in that storeList. As stated by @SaviourSelf, you can use later instanceof to distinguish when traversing the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use instanceof operator to find out which kind of item you have. But this isn't great OOD.

The alternative is a little tricky because you want set a double in one case and an int in the other. But in a web scenario, I assume you're getting the value as a String. So Item could be made abstract and have an abstract setCountOrWeight(String s). And then the subclasses would both override it with their own setCountOrWeight(String s) methods which would know how to parse and set the correct data type.